Customize CarLauncher in Android Automotive OS
I need to customize the Default CarLauncher in Android Automotive OS.
How can I replace the Default CarLauncher ? How to change the layout and applications displayed on it?
Here is my carLauncher
My Default CarLauncher
I want achieve something look like
This

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
